# Compile IDL file error

Tags: idl

I'm using VS 2008 Pro.
I have 1 idl file which contains:

```
module views {

    // Introduced in DOM Level 2:
    interface [
        ObjCCustomImplementation,
        OmitConstructor
    ] AbstractView {
        readonly attribute Document document;
        readonly attribute Media styleMedia;
    };

}
```

(That's all, no more in the file.)
When I build the file (right click to file and press Compile, error occurs as following:

AbstractView.idl
..\page\AbstractView.idl(30) : error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a type specification near "interface"
..\page\AbstractView.idl(31) : error MIDL2026 : cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting compilation

What is the problem? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be other way. As far as I remember, first you must define attributes, then interface itself. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be useful.

Comment: I try to use attribute as followed:

module views {

 // Introduced in DOM Level 2:
 [
  uuid(ba209999-0c6c-11d2-97cf-00c04f8eea45),
  version(1.0)
 ]
 interface AbstractView {
  readonly attribute Document document;
  readonly attribute Media styleMedia;
 };

}

But the same error occurs

Comment: It can be so that you are using interface in a wrong way. How do you import it? Could you please show a bit more of your code?

Comment: In fact, I don't know much about idl. I'm porting WebKit and met the problem. It is sent when building MIDL. I really don't understand about this.

Comment: Well, the problem with IDL-compiler is that all its error messages are too abstract. So, you must be able to recognise the situation when this message can appear. As I wrote previously post complete code of your idl-module, maybe together we will find an error :)

Comment: besworland, thank you so much. I'm so sorry about my stupid. In fact, quoted source code above is all in the file. I will investigate source code more and try to find the way to describe to you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a CORBA IDL file rather than a MIDL file.